# Xslt distinct values and add element to existing xml dynamically

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to change format of an existing xml with xslt. I am able to get all distinct IDs but are having problem to set price and country element to the distinct IDs And are having trouble with it. Need to transform the below xml

```
<result>
    <data>
        <ID>7705379</ID>
        <value>54</value>
        <country>lv</country>
        <price>24.99</price>
    </data>
    <data>
        <ID>7705379</ID>
        <value>54</value>
        <country>fi</country>
        <price>24.99</price>
    </data>
        <data>
        <ID>7111111</ID>
        <value>503</value>
        <country>fi</country>
        <price>19.99</price>
    </data>
        <data>
        <ID>7111111</ID>
        <value>503</value>
        <country>se</country>
        <price>119.99</price>
    </data>
</result>
```

to something that looks like this.

```
 <data>
        <Product>
            <Fields>
                <ID>7705379</ID>
                <ProductST>
                    <Key id="SE" >
                        <Value>54</Value>
                    </Key>
                </ProductST>
                <ProductPrice>
                    <Key id="lv" >
                        <Value>24.99</Value>
                    </Key>
                    <Key id="fi" >
                        <Value>24.99</Value>
                    </Key>
                </ProductPrice>
            </Fields>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Fields>
                <ID>7111111</ID>
                <ProductST>
                    <Key id="SE" >
                        <Value>503</Value>
                    </Key>
                </ProductST>
                <ProductPrice>
                    <Key id="fi" >
                        <Value>19.99</Value>
                    </Key>
                    <Key id="se" >
                        <Value>119.99</Value>
                    </Key>
                </ProductPrice>
            </Fields>
        </Product>
    </data>
```

Comment: Can you share the XSLT that you have written? What is the relation of  attribute `id` of element `<Key>` to the data in the input XML? There seems to a mismatch between the data of input and output XML.

Comment: The value of element <country> skould be used as attribute id of element <Key>
<xsl:key name="productid" match="/result/row/ID/text()" use="." />/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<data>
  <xsl:for-each select="/result/row/ID/text()[generate-id()
                                       = generate-id(key('productid',.)[1])]">
 <ID>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </ID>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the input XML shared, there are some discrepancies in the shared output XML. It will be difficult to list them out in the comments hence including them in the solution.

1. Values corresponding to `<country>` element from input XML do not match with few `<Key id="">` elements of the output.
2. `<ProductST>` has a single `<Key>` child element in the output whose attribute `id` has a value of `SE` which is not present in the input XML.
3. `<ProductPrice>` has correct number of child `<Key>` elements whose `id` attribute values match with the values of `<country>` from the input in 3 out of 4 instances.

Assuming there is a mismatch between the data used in input XML and output XML, you can try the below XSLT solution that should give a close enough idea on grouping the values. This solution is based on the input XML and hence will not match with the shared output XML.

```
<xsl:key name="kId" match="data" use="ID" />
<xsl:template match="result">
    <data>
        <xsl:for-each select="data[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kId', ID)[1])]">
            <Product>
                <Fields>
                    <ID><xsl:value-of select="key('kId', ID)/ID" /></ID>
                    <ProductST>
                        <Key>
                            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                <xsl:value-of select="'SE'" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <Value><xsl:value-of select="key('kId', ID)/value" /></Value>
                        </Key>
                    </ProductST>
                    <ProductPrice>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('kId', ID)">
                            <Key>
                                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="country" />
                                </xsl:attribute>
                                <Value><xsl:value-of select="price" /></Value>
                            </Key>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ProductPrice>
                </Fields>
            </Product>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </data>
</xsl:template>
```

This generates the following output

```
<data>
    <Product>
        <Fields>
            <ID>7705379</ID>
            <ProductST>
                <Key id="SE">
                    <Value>54</Value>
                </Key>
            </ProductST>
            <ProductPrice>
                <Key id="lv">
                    <Value>24.99</Value>
                </Key>
                <Key id="fi">
                    <Value>24.99</Value>
                </Key>
            </ProductPrice>
        </Fields>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Fields>
            <ID>7111111</ID>
            <ProductST>
                <Key id="SE">
                    <Value>503</Value>
                </Key>
            </ProductST>
            <ProductPrice>
                <Key id="fi">
                    <Value>19.99</Value>
                </Key>
                <Key id="se">
                    <Value>119.99</Value>
                </Key>
            </ProductPrice>
        </Fields>
    </Product>
</data>
```

**EDIT:** Solution has been updated according to comment.

Comment: I´m sorry i wasn´t very clear in my question. good to find discrepancies in the output xm.l I have updated in question.

Comment: About point 2. I wan´t very clear there as well. >ProductST> element should always have on child <Key> with the harcoded id of "SE". But you have already helped me very much. Thanks for that.

Comment: I have updated the solution accordingly. Now you will have one child `<Key>` with attribute `id = "SE"` (hardcoded) for `<ProductST>` and appropriate `<Value>`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you have really helped me here. Will accept your answear. Unfortunately i can´t upvote because of my low rating but will comeback and up vote once my rank is higher.